# Making a 9 digit number divisible by 11

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, game

Alice and Bob play the following game, taking turns. Alice starts and writes a non-zero single
digit number at the blackboard.
At every turn, each player adds a single digit at the right of the current number until a number
with 9 digits is reached.
If this number is divisible by 11, Alice wins otherwise Bob.

Who has a winning strategy?

Comment: Does only the first digit need to be non-zero? You don't state anything about every other digits and I believe it might change the answer for your puzzle

Comment: only the first digit must be non-zero, there is no restriction for the other digits.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Note: This answer assumes that the non-zero restriction only holds for the first move, not for any subsequent digits, i.e. that the restriction was imposed only to ensure a valid 9-digit number was produced.

The winning player is

> Bob

using the following strategy:

> There is a well-known trick for reducing a number modulo 11, namely adding the digits at the odd positions and subtracting those at the even positions. In other words, Alice's moves minus Bob's moves results in a much smaller number with the same remainder mod 11 as the original nine-digit number.
>
>  Bob can do as his first move one less than Alice's digit, and in subsequent moves just copy Alice's digits. This ensures that the number is 1 modulo 11 after each of Bob's moves. Alice's last move can only result in a number that is 1 to 10 modulo 11, but not zero because that would require a digit of value 10.

Comment: The divisibility trick works because $10\equiv-1$ (mod 11). Therefore $10^2\equiv+1$ (then apply linearity to the sum of digits x place position. Also interesting is that the first-turn restriction makes a difference.

Comment: If that strategy were to work, there is a weakness: What if Alice starts with a 1? Bob has no move but to copy that and wait for a chance. What if Alice only plays 1s? It breaks down. But then it seems it does not work anyway. (trying not to reveal spoilers in this comment makes it harder to be clear what I mean, sorry!)

Comment: @AdamV If Alice only plays ones, the number will be 101111111, which is not divisible by 11, making Bob win. Bob does not copy Alice in the first move.

Comment: I think I misread that no numbers could be 0, not just the first for some reason.

Comment: @AdamV Fair enough. On re-reading the question that is a little ambiguous. I assumed it was only on the first digit in order to make it a valid number without leading zeroes, and I hope I was right in that assumption.

Answer (score 9):

[Edit: I read the puzzle as requiring all digits to be non-zero, in which specific case...] The winning player is always

> Bob

Because

> As he plays the 8th digit, Bob must make the 8-digit number be divisible by 11. In order for the 9 digit number to also be divisible by 11, Alice would have to play a zero, which is not allowed.

The simplest way to achieve that goal is

> to ensure the 8 digit number is divisible by 11 by copying every digit that Alice plays. A number of the form aabbccdd will always be divisible by 11.

Comment: aabbccdd is eight digits, not the nine that are required. Alice has both the first and the last move in the game.

Comment: Yes, but since aabbccdd is divisible by 11, she has no move except a zero. But I may have misread that as a restriction on all digits, not just the first. I can't downvote my own answer though...

Comment: Maybe you can just edit your answer to explicitly state that assumption/interpretation, like I did with my answer just now.

Answer (score 2):

*If* the leading digit *could* be zero, which it can't, but if it *could*, then

> Alice wins

by

> playing $0$ first, then copying all of Bob's moves.

This results in

> an eight digit number of the form $AABBCCDD$, which is always divisible by eleven.

Note that

> this is the same as Bob's winning strategy in the original game, but with a different opening.

@obscurans pointed this out in a comment